# order different part of queryset

Tags: python, django, partial-ordering

I have some problem. I need to use two ordering for different part of queryset. It means: order all -> order first part -> order second part

```
for item in queryset:
        if not item.state.sold:
            on_sale_count +=1

    queryset.order_by('finished_at')
    queryset.order_by('-started_at')[:on_sale_count]
    queryset.order_by('-started_at')[on_sale_count+1:]
```

Comment: Querysets cannot be partially ordered. Why not assigning them to different variables for your 3 querysets and use them separately?

Comment: I have solved problem
ordering = ('state__sold','-state__finished_date','-start_at', )

Comment: Congratulations! but how was anyone to know that your model even had fields like that?